# how to prove $ F(\bar{x})=\bar{x} $

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

I need to have a hint. I even don't know how to start. Please leave your comments in the bellow.

> Let 
>   $(X,d)$ 
>   be a complete metric space and let 
>   $F:X\to X.$ 
>   Define the 
>   $ n-th $ 
>   iteration of 
>   $F$ 
>   as follows: 
>   $$ F_n(x) :=\underbrace{(F\circ F\circ\cdots \circ F)}_{n-times}(x), $$ 
>   and assume for each 
>   $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ 
>   the existence of 
>   $ \alpha_{n} \geq 0 $ 
>   such that
>   $$ d(F_{n}(x),F_{n}(y))\leq \alpha_{n}d(x,y),\;\; \forall x,y\in X. $$
>   Prove that, if
>   $ \sum_{n}\alpha_{n}<+\infty, $
>   then there exists a unique
>   $\bar{x}\in X$
>   such that
>   $ F(\bar{x})=\bar{x}. $

Comment: I saw a similar problem where I was asked to prove $F$ has a unique fixed point, but the assumption on $F$ is "weaker", that it is only assumed that for some $k\in\Bbb N$, $F_k$ is a contraction, instead of existence of those $\alpha_n$ and $\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}\alpha_n\lt\infty$. You may try to prove using the weaker assumption, because your assumption on $F$ certainly implies the weaker assumption.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I don't know how to relate $F_n$ to $F$ and and to prove that $F$ has a Contraction property.

Comment: @edm, note that in your problem, $a_n = c^n$, where $c$ is the contraction factor. After this observation, you realize that the purpose of the $a_n$ is to abstract the convergence properties of $c^n$.

Comment: @HamedBaghalGhaffari I did not say that $F$ is a contraction mapping. We only want to prove $F$ has a unique fixed point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very weak generalization of the Banach fixed point theorem and is easily google-able. If you're interested in tackling it on your own, here's an outline:

1. establish uniqueness by assuming $F(x) = x$ and $F(y) = y$ and proving that $x = y$ (hint: you need an implication of $\sum a_n < \infty$ and $a_n \geq 0$
2. establish the continuity of $F$ (hint: this is effectively given to you in the problem)
3. establish existence of $\bar x$ by taking an arbitrary $x \in X$ and considering the sequence $F(x), F_2(x), F_3(x),\dots$. Show this sequence converges by showing that it is Cauchy (hint: you need that the partial sums of $\sum a_n$ are Cauchy)
4. Call the limit $\bar x$. Show that $F(\bar x) = \bar x$ by considering $\lim F_n(x)$ and $\lim F_{n+1}(x)$ and using part 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did it.

Answer (score 3):

First show that for some $k\in\Bbb N$, $\alpha_k\lt1$, which is obvious from $\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}\alpha_n\lt\infty$. So we have that $F_k$ is a contraction mapping, and hence has a unique fixed point $\bar x$ by Banach fixed point theorem.

To prove uniqueness of fixed point of $F$, let $y\in X$ be a fixed point of $F$ (if such a point $y$ exists) and show that $y=\bar x$, which is obvious because $y$ is a fixed point of $F_k$ as well and hence equal to $\bar x$, i.e. if $F$ has a fixed point, it would be $\bar x$.

To prove $\bar x$ is really a fixed point of $F$, we pay attention to the two points $F(\bar x),F_k(F(\bar x))$. Note that $F_k(F(\bar x))=F_{k+1}(\bar x)=F(F_k(\bar x))=F(\bar x)$, i.e. $F(\bar x)$ is also a fixed point of $F_k$, which means $F(\bar x)=\bar x$ by uniqueness of fixed point of $F_k$.